# Autocompletion of makefile with makro in zsh not correct (works in bash)

Tags: zsh, make, autocomplete

I have a makefile that has the targets

- start-prod
- start-test
- stop-prod
- stop-test
- restart-prod
- restart-test

Autocompletion works in bash without problems but in zsh it will only complete `start-` etc. not `start-prod`.

The targets are defined with makros.

```
define commands =
$(eval
restart-$(1):   stop-$(1) start-$(1)
start-$(1):     ; docker-compose up -d --remove-orphans $(1)
stop-$(1):      ; docker-compose stop $(1)
)
endef


$(call commands,prod)
$(call commands,test)
```

My assumption is that bash evaluates the makefiles to get the targets while zsh try to parse it.

Is there any way to get this working in zsh.

I tried to use the bash command in zsh like mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8492043/3485361). But this only got me an error when I try to complete an makefile

```
_init_completion: command not found zsh
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bash calls `make` with options that make it print out the evaluated makefile in a normalized form. Zsh can do this as well, but by default it uses its own parser. Calling `make` gives more precise information, but since it evaluates things like `$(shell)` commands inside the makefile, it can be slower and is dangerous in the rare case where you don't trust the content of the makefile (that would be pretty rare though, since the reason you'd use completion is because you plan to run `make` anyway).

To make zsh call the `make` command, enable the [`call-command`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-call_002dcommand_002c-completion-style) [completion](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#Overview-1) [style](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#index-zstyle). (To find out the exact style pattern to set, looking at the trace generated when `set -x` is active is easier than figuring out the documentation.)

```
zstyle ':completion::complete:make:*:targets' call-command true
```

Replace `make` by `*` for it to apply to other completions such as for `ant`.

Even with this feature enabled, zsh won't call `make` if it isn't GNU make, so you can enable it everywhere without loss of functionality. (Bash does, so bash's completion doesn't work with other make implementations.)

Comment: Thank you. that was exactly what I needed :)

Comment: FWIW, this may have worked, but I wound up using a more explicit solution as I worked through the following issue: I had made a typo in a fresh makefile, and with this solution zsh output all of the environment variables I might want to set while calling make.  This behavior was different than bash completion under similar conditions and sent me looking for more solutions.  Long story short: verify your makefile works prior to trying this.